# How to fetch partial data from a large yaml file?

Tags: python, yaml

I have a large yaml file containing some useless data. When using yaml.load() to load this file, memory consumption exceeds  the physical limit of our computer. I can't read it. Whether I can only read partial data which I need to a python dict? are there some library or code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using PyYaml, you can do something like this:

```
with open("file.yaml", 'r') as handle:
  for event in yaml.parse(handle):
    # handle the event here
```

This processes the YAML file event by event, instead of loading it all into a data structure. Of course, you now need to parse the structure manually from the event stream, but this allows you to *not* process parts of the data further.

You can look at PyYaml's [Composer implementation](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib3/yaml/composer.py#L29) to see how it constructs Python objects from events, and what structure it expects from the event stream.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another technique I found useful when you have control over the format of the YAML output. Instead of having the data be a single structure, you can split it up into separate YAML documents by using the "---" separator. For example, instead of

```
- foo: 1
  bar: 2
- foo: 2
  bar: 10
```

You can write this as:

```
foo: 1
bar: 2
---
foo: 2
bar: 10
```

and then use the following python code to parse it:

```
with open("really_big_file.yaml") as f:
    for item in yaml.load_all(f):
        print(item)
```